# Is it possible to search pdf file in whole iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I want to search each and every pdf files on whole iphone.Is it possible in iphone sdk?
I have tried following code but it is giving our own application's files.

```
 NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
 NSArray *onlyPDFs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each application (and its associated files) are sandboxed under iOS, hence you won't be able to access files other than those produced by your own application.

i.e.: This isn't possible.